# How to install ssl certificate with Apache and Nginx

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server running with Apache and Nginx. I want to add an SSL certificate using Certbot but I don't know how to proceed.

My project consists of a django api and a Vue js frontend.
Nginx is responsible for the API and apache acts as a reverse proxy.

My Apache 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ***.***.** <- My IP
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

My Nginx config

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/backend/mysite.sock;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name mysite.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/backend/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/backend/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/backend/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thank you if someone informs me how can I install an ssl certificate with Certbot using this configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

- apache: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-apache
- nginx: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx